# UITableViewSource. Вывод данных из List

Tags: c#, xamarin, monotouch

Здравствуйте!

Я делаю приложение, которое будет выводить расписание занятий, и тут я столкнулся с проблемой, как выводит данные из `List<Lesson>` в ячейки в UITableView, если `IndexPath.Row` начинается с нуля при переходе в новую секцию.

Есть 2 варианта заполнения xml с расписанием.

Первый вариант:

```
<timetable>
    <lesson>
        <nameOfLesson>Chemistry</nameOfLesson>
        <day>16.02.2015</day>
        <weekday>Monday</weekday>
        <time>11:05-12:35</time>
        <audience>514</audience>
    </lesson>
    <lesson>
        <nameOfLesson>Mathematics</nameOfLesson>
        <day>16.02.2015</day>
        <weekday>Monday</weekday>
        <time>13:00-14:30</time>
        <audience>514</audience>
    </lesson>
<timetable>
```

И второй:

```
<timetable>
    <day>
        <lesson>
            <nameOfLesson></nameOfLesson>
            <date>16.02.2015</date>
            <weekday>Monday</weekday>
            <time>11:05-12:35</time>
            <audience>514</audience>
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            <nameOfLesson></nameOfLesson>
            <date>16.02.2015</date>
            <weekday>Monday</weekday>
            <time>13:00-14:30</time>
            <audience>514</audience>
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            <nameOfLesson></nameOfLesson>
            <date>16.02.2015</date>
            <weekday>Monday</weekday>
            <time>14:40-16:10</time>
            <audience>514</audience>
        </lesson>
    </day>
    <day>
        <lesson>
            <nameOfLesson></nameOfLesson>
            <date>17.02.2015</date>
            <weekday>Tuesday</weekday>
            <time>13:00-14:30</time>
            <audience>602</audience>
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            <nameOfLesson></nameOfLesson>
            <date>17.02.2015</date>
            <weekday>Tuesday</weekday>
            <time>14:40-16:10</time>
            <audience>602</audience>
        </lesson>
    </day>
</timetable>
```

Вот так выглядит класс Lesson:

```
public class Lesson
{
    public string name, day, dayOfWeek, time, audience;
    public Lesson(string _name, string _day, string _dayOfWeek, string _time, string _audience)
    {
         this.name = _name;
         this.day = _day;
         this.dayOfWeek = _dayOfWeek;
         this.time = _time;
         this.audience = _audience;
    }
}
```

Все у меня, по сути, есть, только я немного не понимаю, как лучше вытаскивать нужные данные из List в нужную ячейку UITableView, так как в List всё по порядку, а IndexPath.Row нет.

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал сам

Comment: @Adept, опубликуйте решение. Может, кто-нибудь столкнется с такой же проблемой